Action Required: Apple Push Notification Service Server Certificate Update
How to Update Trust Store for APNs with USERTrust RSA Certification Authority Certificate?
Apple is updating the APNs server certificates. The sandbox environment will switch on January 20, 2025, and production on February 24, 2025, to the USERTrust RSA Certification Authority (SHA-2 Root).
Questions:

How do I add the new USERTrust RSA certificate to my app’s Trust Store?
How can I ensure both old and new certificates are supported before the cut-off dates?
Are there any tests or configurations required to verify the update?

Apple states no changes are needed for APNs SSL provider certificates—can anyone confirm this?
Any advice or steps for a smooth transition would be appreciated!

See Should I prepare to Apple renewal of APNs USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate?.

If you use Firebase,  it seems there is nothing you need to do on your side, see this answer.

We are currently utilizing a token-based connection (p8 key) for APNs. Do we need to make any changes regarding this? @aymen2709

First of all, don't panic! USERTrust RSA Certification Authority (the authority Apple will be using since January 20th) is widely supported since 2015: you can test your local PC by just visiting this site in a browser. Probabily your app is fine already.
That said, it depends on your environment: this is a matter for a system admin, not a mobile developer.
If your backend app (the one that actually opens connections to APNS) runs on a server, just install the new certs there...or just update the server.
If your backend app is containerized you should be good by just rebuilding the app targeting an updated base image. Once again, if it's not a very old server  you need to do nothing.
If you have access to the server you can easily check if you have the right certs installed, by running this command
openssl s_client -connect usertrustrsacertificationauthority-ev.comodoca.com:443
which opens an SSL connection to the demo site above that uses a cert signed by USERTrust RSA Certification Authority. Then in January you can test the APNS developement environment to be sure you're ok.
